Params not showing in class constructor in ABAP Eclipse
I created a local class with a constructor that get two parameters as inputs:
CLASS lcl_connection DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    DATA carrier_id    TYPE str.
    DATA connection_id TYPE str.
    CLASS-DATA conn_counter TYPE i.
    METHODS:
      constructor
        IMPORTING
          i_carrier_id    TYPE str
          i_connection_id TYPE str.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_connection IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD constructor.
    me->carrier_id = i_carrier_id.
    me->connection_id = i_connection_id.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

When I want to create an object and pass values to these params. Also, new #( i_carrier_id='q' ) ctrl+space is not working here and doesn't suggest the second param, and if I write by myself, it shows me the error.
Also, ctrl+1 doesn't suggest anything. new #( i_carrier_id='q' ) ctrl+space not working here.
CLASS zcl_01_local_class DEFINITION
  PUBLIC
  FINAL
  CREATE PUBLIC .
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    INTERFACES if_oo_adt_classrun .
  PROTECTED SECTION.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS zcl_01_local_class IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD if_oo_adt_classrun~main.
    DATA connection TYPE REF TO lcl_connection.
    out->write( 'hello').
    connection = new #( i_carrier_id='q'  ). 
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

Error:

The parameter name can be omitted only if the method has only one non-optional IMPORTING parameter or one optional IMPORTING parameter identified by "PREFERRED PARAMETER". by "PREFERRED PARAMETER".

- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2024-06 (4.32.0)
Build id: 20240606-1231
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java runtime version: 21.0.1+12-LTS-29
Java version: 21.0.1

- ABAP: latest version



In ABAP, spaces are mandatory at many places, especially around =.

Thank you @SandraRossi, it is working now

Thanks to @SandraRossi, I add space before of = and it works
connection = new #( i_carrier_id ='q' i_connection_id ='b' ). 


Although ='q' is permitted, 99.9% of people and tools put a space also after = (= 'q'), especially because of the rule for numbers: =1 is not permitted, = 1 is permitted.
